# Web-Crawling down to a table

Tags: python, html, python-requests, web-crawler, reverse-engineering

I'm looking to scrape the tables on the following website https://www.pro14rugby.org/match-centre/results.

There is a widget that switches between seasons. All of the data is held in tables after the point of this widget switcher.

The html I am extracting is only going as far as the widget switcher.

I am new to web scraping so a point in the right direction would be very welcome.

I've looked in network to see if there is a url to get me passed this point.

```
def download(url, user_agent='<My_Email>', num_retries=2):

    print('Downloading:', url)
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
    try:
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        html = resp.text
        if resp.status_code >= 400:
            print('Download error:', resp.text)
            html = None
            if num_retries and 500 <= resp.status_code < 600:
                # recursively retry 5xx HTTP errors
                return download(url, num_retries - 1)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print('Download error:', e)
        html = None
    return html

page='https://www.pro14rugby.org/match-centre/results'

html=download(page)
```

Expecting to see html code with a path through to the data, as i see it when I inspect. I understand that the widget is dynamic so it makes sense that I would need to enter the criteria in the code to get each season out. Any advice on doing this would be very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you can't get the round 1 round 2 etc for 2018-19? Or you can't get other years?

Comment: I can't get anything. Looking at the html that I have downloaded, I have a div class='bodyMain', within that I have a select class='widgetswitcher' (data is each season) and a div class = 'widget'. The data i require is nested in the div class = 'widget' when i inspect the page but nothing further in the downloaded html.

Answer (score 1):

The site uses `jQuery` to display table with the season when selected. It's probably not possible to scrape it with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. `Selenium` can be used to scrape the text as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.pro14rugby.org/match-centre/results")

for i in range(18):
    s= Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('widgetSwitcher'))
    s.select_by_index(i)
    time.sleep(6)
    val = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sotic-widget').text
    print(val.replace('REPORT',''))

driver.quit()
```

The script prints all the text in the tables and exits.

Comment: that's what I needed, time to get stuck into selenium so. Much appreciated

Comment: There seems to be an API in the site , if you can figure it out maybe you'll be able to scrape without `selenium`